# Paypal CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile billing for firstmonth automatically

Tags: payment-gateway, paypal, paypal-subscriptions, recurring-billing

I need to know how to pay for the first month while calling the CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile,
current situation is that I am able to make a initial payment at the time of creation of the profile, but I want to make the first month payment of the recurring payment.

My current request parameters are below

```
METHOD=CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile&VERSION=61.0&PWD=XXXXXX&USER=ramjio_1265317521_biz_api1.gmail.com&SIGNATURE=A1ztEX-EPedHf6p5.GxbRz1NXQj9A0lzO7zyE.0s4BzXkJhRpTZhCjxz&TOKEN=EC-0KM07981VB102461N&AMT=100&INITAMT=100&CURRENCYCODE=USD&PROFILESTARTDATE=2010-02-13T02%3A47%3A38&BILLINGPERIOD=Month&BILLINGFREQUENCY=1&TOTALBILLINGCYCLES=12&L_BILLINGTYPE0=RecurringPayments&L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0=1+Month+Free&DESC=1+Month+Free&MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS=5&AUTOBILLOUTAMT=AddToNextBilling
```

so the current profile shows like below

Payment cycle Monthly
Total cycles 12 
Cycles remaining 12 
Amount due per cycle $100.00 USD  
Amount received $0.00 USD

But I need something like the below
Payment cycle Monthly 
Total cycles 12 
Cycles remaining 11 
Amount due per cycle $100.00 USD  
Amount received $100.00 USD

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your requirements are, but you might be able to set the profile start date to the date of the notional second recurring payment, and the "initial amount" to the amount to cover the amount of the first month's payment.  It would show 11 cycles remaining (out of 11) though.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

1. Take the initial payment of $100 for the initial transaction.
2. Add a trial period for a user for a Month.
3. Then bill the user accordingly as per your defined schedule of 11 cycles.